# Sequelize attributes on include are overwriting defaultScope

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have this model Bar, define like this

```
const Bar = sequelize.define(
  'Bar',
  {
    id: DataTypes.STRING,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  {
    defaultScope: {
      attributes: ['id']
    },
    scopes: {
      withName: {
        attributes: {
          include: ['name']
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

when i include it in a find, it gets added, with only the id showing

```
Foo.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Bar, // defaultScope does its work
  }],
})
/* 
{
  ...
  Bar:[
    {
      id: qux
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

so far, all is well
but when i want to also include the name field of Bar, the id does not get returned.

```
Foo.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Bar,
    attributes: { include: ['name'] } // defaultScope get ignored
  }],
})
/* 
{
  ...
  Bar:[
    {
      name: quux
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

i can however create a second scope and request it together with the defaultscope, but this will become cumbersome to create separate scopes every time

```
Foo.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Bar.scope(['defaultScope', 'withName']) // extra scope 'withName' means extra upkeep/maintenance on the model every time you want extra fields
  }],
})
/* 
{
  ...
  Bar:[
    {
      id: qux,
      name: quux
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

**is there a way to add fields to an include on findAll (or findOne or findByPk) without having to define separate scopes every time?**

i know i can add the fields of the defaultScope that i want also in the attributes, but that would defeat the whole purpose of the defaultScope

```
Foo.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: Bar,
    attributes: { include: ['id','name'] } // defeats the purpose of defaultScope
  }],
})
/* 
{
  ...
  Bar:[
    {
      id: qux,
      name: quux
    }
  ]
}
*/
```

Edit: or is the overwriting behaviour a bug in sequelize?
(i am running this on 5.21.4, i have not tested 6+ yet)

Comment: It is my understanding that defaultScope applies when no other scope is supplied, and by defining explicit attributes to return you are overriding it, as when you specify the `withName` scope. What is your ultimate goal? I would either define a scope that explicitly includes what you want in that scope, OR specify individual attributes in your query.

Comment: my ultimate goal would be to use both scopes and explicit attributes at the same time. - 
because my model has lots of attributes, some of them useful in most situations, but most of them only useful in 1 specific situation. - 
it would be annoying to add a scope for every specific situation that requires 1 extra attribute as compared to an existing scope (2nd last example). - 
and it is also annoying to specify every attribute that a scope already has, just because i want 1 extra attribute (last example).

Comment: I would think of this as a "mixin" process and include a base scope and the more typical additional scopes that you'd want, e.g. `Bar.scope(['base', 'withStatuses', 'withDates'])` or `Bar.scope(['baseExtended', 'withStatuses', 'withDates', 'withAccounting'])`